# Is "then comes the end" in 1 Corinthians 15:24 an allusion to Daniel 12:6-13?

Tags: 1-corinthians, referent-identification, daniel, messiah

Is "the end" in 1 Corinthians 15:24 an allusion to Daniel 12:6-13?:

> [1Co 15:19-28 ESV] (19) If in Christ we have **hope** in this life only, we are of all people most to be pitied. (20) But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep. (21) For as by a man came death, by a man has come also the resurrection of the dead. (22) For as in Adam all die, so also in Christ shall all be made alive. (23) But each in his own order: Christ the firstfruits, then at his coming those who belong to Christ. (24) **Then comes the end**, when he delivers the kingdom to God the Father after destroying every rule and every authority and power. (25) For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet. (26) The last enemy to be destroyed is death. (27) For "God has put all things in subjection under his feet." But when it says, "all things are put in subjection," it is plain that he is excepted who put all things in subjection under him. (28) **When all things are subjected to him**, then the Son himself will also be subjected to him who put all things in subjection under him, that God may be all in all.
>
> [Dan 12:6-13 NKJV] (6) And one said to the man clothed in linen, who was above the waters of the river, **"How long shall the fulfillment of these wonders be?"** (7) Then I heard the man clothed in linen, who was above the waters of the river, when he held up his right hand and his left hand to heaven, and swore by Him who lives forever, that **it shall be for a time, times, and half a time; and when the power of the holy people has been completely shattered, all these things shall be finished. (8) Although I heard, I did not understand. Then I said, "My lord, **what shall be the end of these things?**"  (9) And he said, "Go your way, Daniel, for **the words are closed up and sealed till the time of the end.** (10) "Many shall be purified, made white, and refined, but the wicked shall do wickedly; and none of the wicked shall understand, but the wise shall understand. **(11) "And from the time that the daily sacrifice is taken away, and the abomination of desolation is set up, there shall be one thousand two hundred and ninety days. (12) "Blessed is he who waits, and comes to the one thousand three hundred and thirty-five days. (13) "But you, go your way till the end; for you shall rest, and will arise to your inheritance at the end of the days."**

Answer (score 0):

> (24) Then comes the end, when he delivers the kingdom to God the
>   Father after destroying every rule and every authority and power. (25)
>   For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet.
>   (26) The last enemy to be destroyed is death.

The key words in this passage are "kingdom" and "for he must reign until..."  This makes me think that "the end" in this passage is referring to a period of time after the millennial reign of Christ on Earth.

> (11) "And from the time that the daily sacrifice is taken away, and
>   the abomination of desolation is set up, there shall be one thousand
>   two hundred and ninety days. (12) "Blessed is he who waits, and comes
>   to the one thousand three hundred and thirty-five days. (13) "But you,
>   go your way till the end; for you shall rest, and will arise to your
>   inheritance at the end of the days."

I believe "the end" here refers to the end of the tribulation period before the 1,000 year reign of Christ on earth.

Comment: Is Daniel 12:9-13 *also* a reference to the same time and situation?

Comment: The way I understand it now:  Daniel is referencing the 7 year tribulation period.  Events in order:  Rapture of the church, 7 year period of tribulation - Dan's passage, 1,000 year reign of Jesus on Earth, kingdom handed over to the Father (1 Cor) New Heavens and New Earth.  I think Daniels passage and 1 Corinthians could be separated by 1,000 years.  I could be wrong.

Comment: So "the end" in Corinthians is not an allusion to "the end" in Daniel? Different "the ends"?

Comment: I think so:  Daniel - end of the tribulation period, 1 Cor - end of the millennial reign

Answer (score 0):

**The End of the World** The End of the World with the General Resurrection of the Dead, some unto eternal life, and some to damnation, is definitely mentioned in 1 Corinthians 15! Death is defeated (abolished), and the Kingdom of Jesus is handed over to the Father (15:24). This teaching of Paul coincides with the Kingdom parables of Jesus in Matthew 13. (the *synteleias*, Gk.)

The passage in Daniel referred to this as well--but only verse 13!   *But go your way till the End; for you shall rest, and will rise to your inheritance at the End of Days.*

**End of the Temple** The rest of the uses of "the End" in this chapter refer to the End of the Jewish nation, the End of the Mosaic Sacrificial system. This was *when the power of the holy people has been completely shattered!* (12:7)

- No more Temple
- No more daily sacrifice (continual offering)
- No more genealogies
- No more Holy of Holies
- No more priesthood
- No more sacrifice on Day of Atonement
- No more Passover Lamb

The time of trampling by these Gentile Roman and Gentile mercenaries that it would take to accomplish this was to be *time, times, and a half*. That is 3 and 1/2 years...exactly the time that the Roman General, Vespasian, and his son Titus did this. Trampling up and down Galilee, Perea, Samaria, Judea, and Philistia, from the Spring of 67 A.D. to the Fall of 70 A.D. Exactly 3 and 1/2 years!

**End of the End** That this horrible devastation was to be farther down the road of history was emphasized by the admonition that *the words are to be closed up and sealed till the time of the end*. THE END spoken of here is the End of the Jewish nation (End of the War), not the End of the world!  Recall that the whole prophecy of Daniel 10-12 is a description of the Second Temple Era...which came to an END in 70 A.D.

Daniel is so disturbed by this revelation that he asked, *My Lord, what shall be the End of these things?* (v. 8). Then the angel was more specific, and gave the exact number of days that the Romans would accomplish this finality: 1290 days--->1335 days. This list of two days was a reference to the final days of Jerusalem with a holdout of one fortress for 45 days longer than the capture of the rest of the city. Caput! The Finis! The END!

**End of it All** There was an ending of the Old Covenant with the arrival of Jesus: *The Law was given by Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.* (John 1:17) *The Law and the prophets were proclaimed until John. Since that time the Good News of the Kingdom of God is being evangelized!* (Luke 16:16) (See also Hebrews 8:13)

But there is to be an End of this Present Age, as well. The end of the Kingdom Age (Church age) will be marked by the Resurrection mentioned both by the angel in Daniel 12:13b, and by Paul in 1 Cor. 15:19-28. Paul ended his description of the final Resurrection with:

> *Therefore my brothers, stand firm. Let nothing ,move you. Always give yourselves fully to the work of the Lord, because you know that your labor in the Lord is not in vain. (15:58)*

Answer (score -1):

Matt. 24:29-31 and Mark 13:24-27 tell when Christ returns at the end of the tribulation period and sends his angels to gather the elect from the four corners of the earth to meet him in the clouds, as is referenced in 1 Thess. The middle of the 7 yr tribulation period begins the process of refining as by fire of those that follow God. At the end of the second 1260 day period the two witness are killed. Daniel Mentions a 1290 day period, another 30 days in which I believe this gathering of the elect takes place and from 1290-1335 is the battle where Christ defeats the Antichrist in this 45 day period. We return with Him to begin the millennial kingdom and the marriage supper of the Lamb on the 1335th day. Blessed are those who make it to the 1335th day. We are taken out of the day of Gods wrath during the 45 day period when the final judgements are poured out on all who received the mark of the beast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @richard Pecina-This which is given is just a summary of what is believed (Darbyism?), but it isn't real research that deals with the scriptures posed in this site's question. Keep doing expository study of the Bible.  It's great for the soul!

Answer (score -1):

All the prophecy gives the same exact time line.

- Ezekiel 37:1-14 Resurrections
- Ezekiel 37:15-24 Reign
- Ezekiel 38 and
  39 Gog and Magog
- The end

Paul is also giving a stated order; 1 Corinthians 15:23 "every man in his order"

- 1 Corinthians 15:23 Resurrections
- 1 Corinthians 15:25 Reign
- 1 Corinthians 15:26-28 The end described.
  In verse 24 Paul alludes to the end, then goes on to describe it.

We can see that the last enemy to be destroyed in Revelation is death: Rev 20:14
then comes the end when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God: Rev 21:3.
The events described in Revelation directly line up with the order given by Paul,
and directly line up with the order given in Ezekiel.

- Revelation 20:4-5 Resurrections
- Revelation 20:5-7 Reign
- Revelation 20:7-10 Gog and Magog
- Revelation 20:11 - 22:21 The end

These connections show us clearly that they all are speaking of the same one prophecy.

Paul is alluding to the very end;
"then comes the end.. the last enemy to be destroyed is death"
Rev 20:14 "and death and hades were cast into the lake of fire"

The book of Daniel takes us to the start of the 1000 years,
it's events lead up to Rev 20:4-5 but not to Gog and Magog and beyond,
even though there is a reference to the resurrection of the unjust; Daniel 12:2 [Rev 20:13-15] we know from Daniel 9:27, and 11:31 - 11:45, and 12:11 that it is speaking of the beast and false prophet and the tribulation associated with them.

Comment: @mrall- The two scriptures posted in the question need to be researched and dealt with. And the last paragraph is speculation unproven by exegesis.